# Task could not be loaded from assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have an error in one of my projects at work. The error says:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "StyleCopTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly
>   C:\Projects\Project
>   Name\Source\\MSBuild\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.dll. Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that
>   the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
>   dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
>   that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.  DskDirectMarketing.Common

Here I can clearly see that there is problem in the relative path which VS is looking for StyleCop. Here is how it looks like:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\MSBuild\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.targets" />
```

and my SolutionDir declaration looks like this:

```
<SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\</SolutionDir>
```

After some digging I noticed that in the error which prompts me there are 2 slashes:

> C:\Projects\Project Name\Source\MSBuild\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.dll

First thing I tried was to remove the dash from

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)MSBuild\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.targets" />
```

Id didn't worked.
After that I tried to put the absolute path but I had 2 slashes again.

How can I resolve this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the problem not in the path to tasks, but Microsoft.Build.Utilities assembly is missing.

Comment: Hmmm, I will try downloading .Net Framework 3.5 and will try again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on @MaKCbIMKo's answer I installed .Net Framework 3.5 and this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Windows 10, enable the .net framework 3.5 and if does not allow you to do so, open command prompt and run:

```
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```

Comment: I'm using W10 and this worked like a charm, thank you.

Comment: What exactly does this do?  It also seems to assume that source files are locate in d:\sources\sxs  like thats some default location.

Comment: I did some research and I guess this enables 3.5 and downloads the files.  The problem is you make the assumption that peoples source directory is that without specifying.  The best solution is to enable it from turning windows features on off and it will download the files using windows update.  Just an fyi

Comment: This is a solution but you left out details about mounting a .iso of the Windows 10 and that the d: dive in your answer is the mounted .iso. Otherwise your command solved my issue. +1 for encouragement

Answer (score 5):

If you're also using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10, you could try the following:

1. Close your Visual Studio instance.
2. Open **Visual Studio Installer**.
3. On the version of Visual Studio that you're currently using, click on **More** and select **Modify**.
4. Select the **Individual components** tab.
5. Search for **.NET Framework 3.5 development tools**, select it and click on **Modify**.
6. Wait for the modification to finish.
7. Open your project in Visual Studio, then do a **Clean**, followed by a **Build**.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the paths were correct, but visual studio needed to run under elevated permissions to access the file in question.

Answer (score 0):

- We need to use visual studio installer to install the .netframework 3.5 , if the visual studio installer shows both options Visual Studio 2019 and Visual studio Build Tools  2017. follow below step
- If you are using the Visual Studio 2019  ( mine was 16.11.3 but should work for all the versions). you will have Visual studio  2019 and Visual studio build tools 2017 .
- Select the Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 => select modify => go to individual components => select .Net Framework 3.5 development tools
- Then proceed with the installation.
  -Ideally it should work once you re open the Visual studio , if not restart the system